# Remove format specifiers from printf

Tags: c++, printf

I want to use printf to output a text.

If I want to print a text which has previously entered by the user and may contain a `%`, the output is a garbled mess.
This is propably due to `%` being a format specifier in printf, but no value/argument is given.

For example:

```
std::string inputString = "% Test";
printf(inputString.c_str());

Output:  6.698271e-308st
```

Desired output would be: `% Test`

Is there an elegant way to avoid this?
Entering `%%` instead of `%` works, but it's obviously not very user-friendly.

The only other way I see is modifying the input string to automatically replace every single `%` with `%%`. But is this the way to go?
I'm specifically want/need to use `printf`, using `cout` is not possible

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't be using `printf()` in C++ to begin with. It is error prone. Use `std::cout` instead: `std::cout << inputString;`. Also see [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) or the [`{fmt}`](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library. "*using cout is not possible*" - why?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm actually using a library which uses printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prints` always takes a format string as the first parameter. You cannot change that.
However, you can use it to specify that it should just print a string passed as the second argument as is.

```cpp
std::string inputString = "% Test";
printf("%s", inputString.c_str());
```

Note that, while there is no restriction of what char array you can pass as the format string, you should not use strings provided by a user, even if you don't expect any funny characters in it.
It creates an exploitable vulnerability.

Usually, it's the best to use a string literal. It allows the compiler to warn you if you pass incorrect types of arguments. (Compilers don't have to check that but they often do.)

---

Maybe I should mention that `printf` is a C function.
While using it in C++ program is entirely fine, you could consider switching to C++ style streams from the header [`<iostream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream).
They have advantages and disadvantages but I think in your case they would be easier to use, especially that they support `std::string`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string inputString = "% Test";
    std::cout << inputString;
}
```

Comment: Similarly with C: you don't have to pass a string *literal* as the format string. But what OP proposes is dangerous: you should never allow user input to be used as the format string, it creates a vulnerbility that can be exploited.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed all my code to work like this. Works great now.

Answer (score 5):

Either you use this:

```
printf("%s", string.c_str());
```

Or you use the one that doesn't do formatting at all:

```
puts(string.c_str());
```

Note, that `puts` always adds a newline though!

Edit: Added `c_str` to not cause confusion with the actual question.

Comment: I kindof assumed the `c_str` was still implied in both cases. But I see now, that it might indeed cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

`printf`,when used with the `%s` format specifier, requires a pointer to char. You can get that from an `std::string` via the `c_str()` method:

```
std::string inputString = "% Test";
printf("%s", inputString.c_str());
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP knew about `.c_str()` as they used it correctly in the question.